# How to populate input fields dynamically created based on another one after an AJAX request is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML code that dynamically adds barcode[] and description[] input fields to my form, using the onfocusout event, the get_barcode_data JS function below is triggered to get the barcode description, but it only works for a single barcode[] input field:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="barcode[]" name="barcode[]" onfocusout="get_barcode_data(this);"/>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea id="description[]" name="description[]" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
</div>
<div align="center">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_input_button" title="Add row"></a>
</div>
```

The console.log(name) call displays the value I entered on any of the dynamically created barcode[] input fields and the request is successfully done but after that I don't know how to point the response to the right barcode[] and description[] fields:

```js
function get_barcode_data(element)
{
  var name = element.value;
  console.log(name);
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'include/get_barcode_data.php',
      data: {
          barcode: name
      },
      success: function(response){
          if (response == 'FALSE') {
              $('#barcode[]').focus();
              $('#barcode[]').val('');
              $('#description[]').val('');
              var message = 'Invalid barcode.';
              alert( message );
          } else {
              var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
              $('#description').val(res.description);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you able to give this code on online editor like "https://jsfiddle.net" so we can test and update the code.

Comment: You can't use duplicate IDs in your document.  You should use the `this` passed in to your get_barcode_data function to locate where the response should be placed.

Comment: Thanks James, that is exactly what I'm looking for but how do I do it? I'm calling  get_barcode_data(this) using it but once inside the function, how do I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like James pointed out in the comment section, you cant have duplicate IDs in your document. You should either generate unique IDs for each element, or remove the IDs altogether.

If you generate unique IDs, you can pass the generated ID to your event handler and use it to select the correct element.

```html
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="barcode_123" name="barcode[]" onfocusout="get_barcode_data(this, 'description_123');"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="description_123" name="description[]" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_input_button" title="Add row"></a>
    </div>
```

`123` should be a dynamically generated number.

And in your handler:

```
function get_barcode_data(element, target_id)
{
  var name = element.value;
  console.log(name);
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'include/get_barcode_data.php',
      data: {
          barcode: name
      },
      success: function(response){
          if (response == 'FALSE') {
              $(element).focus();
              $(element).val('');
              $('#' + target_id).val('');
              var message = 'Invalid barcode.';
              alert( message );
          } else {
              var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
              $('#' + target_id).val(res.description);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

I would like to point out though, that this is not very good practice. Code like this get hard to maintain and breaks easily.

You would really be better off by learning a well though out framework, like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I have Angular on my queue so I'll learn it for sure but what if I remove the IDs? Can I still achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You have to get a reference to the element in some way. If you get rid of the IDs you could get it via the DOM. Something like `element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('textarea')`.
That could work, but would break if you change your HTML structure.

Comment: I think I can work with this, I'm a backend developer learning frontend stuff so this is not something I'm using at professional level or working on something that might break. Thanks again, Splashdust